# django-template: HTML link tag contains entire html content of base page

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>I want to</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block header %}
        <div id="header-wrap"></div>
        {% endblock %}
        <div id="container">
            {% block error %} {% endblock %}
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% if error %}
    {% block error %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
{% block content %}
    <p><b>Page</b>: {{ page.language }}</p> 
    <p>views: {{ page.page_views}}</p>
    <form action='/suggest' method='post'>
        <textarea name='suggest' rows='10' cols='100'></textarea>
        <input type='hidden' name='page_name' value={{ page.language }}>
        <input type='submit' value='suggest'>
    </form>
    {% for suggestion in suggestions %}
        <p>Suggestion: {{ suggestion.text }}</p>
        <p>Votes: {{ suggestion.votes }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py** returns

```
return render_to_response('page.html', {'page': page, 'suggestions': suggestions})
```

**Problem:**
- when I see the home page(`index.html`), header seems correctly placed(everything is good)
- when I see specific page, header not appearing, when I firebug-ed it, I found the **link** tag contains the entire `index.html` inside it

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
<html>
<head>
<link href="static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>I want to learn</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrap"></div>
<div id="container">
<a href=/page/python>python</a>
<a href=/page/page1>page1</a>
<a href=/page/page1>page2</a>
<a href=/page/page3>page3</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</link>
```

how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just fixed it** :
`- path to stylesheet on pages was relative(static/style.css) and NOT` absolute(***/***static/style.css). Making absolute path makes it work

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
<html>
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I am glad that an answer almost 8 years ago helped you!